# IbPy Installation: Can't open file 'setup.py.in'

Tags: python

I am trying to set up IBPY and Python on my Mac to run with Interactive Brokers, per the documentation at http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades.  I have installed Git.  I created a subdirectory ibapi under Home.  I downloaded IBPy using `git clone https://github.com/blampe/IbPy` from the ibapi directory.  I then tried `python setup.py.in install` to install IbPy as a Python module.  This is the message I received:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py.in': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: What makes you think `python setup.py.in install` is in fact the correct command to run?

Comment: I was following the directions here: http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades

Comment: ...so, here's the thing: When you run `python foo.py`, it's looking for a file named `foo.py`. If you don't have one, it won't work. So, look at what your `git clone` operation creates. Second, `.in` files are, as their name implies, *templates* -- they're _input_ for something like a `configure` script to convert into a usual state, rather than something intended to be run/used as-is. In this case, though, looking at the repo in question, it clearly contains a `setup.py`, but no `setup.py.in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the README](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy#what-else), it clearly states to run:

```
python setup.py install
```

No `.in` involved.

Comment: OK, I tried that.  This is what I got:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I have Python in the Anaconda folder in the Home directory

Comment: Which directory are you in when you run that command? If you aren't in the `IbPy` directory, you'll need to change into it first.

This is, by the way, sounding less like a programming question and more about an end-user installation support question. SuperUser might be a better forum.